# Why is cell losing formula after initial calculation? - Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell, userform

I have an excel sheet that is being fed data from a userform.  Certain cells auto update based upon when certain cells on the *Home* page or *Setup* page change.

On the setup page, cell H1 references cell Home!B15 which is control sourced to my userform.  It takes in a sales rep name.

Cell *H2* has the following formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Home!B15,D2:E243, 2, FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(Home!B15,D2:E243, 2, FALSE))
```

This works fine!

In cell Home!B16, I have the following formula

```
=Setup!H2
```

For whatever reason, it will populate the correct value one time.  Once I select a different sales rep in my userform, it loses the formula, and keeps the first value.

My question again: *Why is my cell losing it's formula after taking on its first value?*

Comment: Formulas do not spontaneously disappear, so some part of your code must be replacing the formula with the cell's value.

Comment: @TimWilliams that is what I had originally figured.  Though, nothing is currently control sourced to B16 on the Home page.  Nothing seems to be overwriting it.  Would you suggest anything I should be looking at first to perhaps further observe this issue?

Comment: Is there any code in the worksheet code module which might be responding to sheet events?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just checked that.  None of my other cells point at the cell in question at any point in time.

Comment: In that case it's pretty difficult to debug without seeing the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue with a userform in VBA/EXCEL 2010. It seems when you change a value in the form that affects the value in a calculated cell, the formula in that cell gets replaced with a literal value. Pretty frustrating.

The best I could do for a workaround it to store the formulas that get lost in another location (in a dictionary object, for example) and then when I close the form I use VBA to overwrite the [new] literal value(s) with the formula(s) that were in those cells to begin with.